# MMA - Long Hair

Tags: protective-equipment, mixed-martial-arts

My hair's longish and I'm looking to start MMA, though I'm loath to chop it off (rather attached, aheh heh) so I'm looking for a solution. I was thinking about tying it up and using something like this

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Cycling-Skull-Cap-Motorbike-Cycle-Under-Helmet-Caps-Windstopper-Thermal-NEW-/151131125013?pt=UK_Cycling_Clothing&var=&hash=item23301df515

together with something like this

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DX-Ear-Guard-MMA-Grappling-Wrestling-Helmet-Head-Gear-BJJ-Boxing-UFC-Rugby-Gear-/261532897474?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_3&hash=item3ce49350c2

It'd also have the added bonus of giving my head some mild protection. Opinions? Any better suggestions?

Thanking any answers in advance :)

Comment: See http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2646/what-are-good-solutions-for-mma-training-with-half-long-hair?rq=1 (not a duplicate but similar question)

Comment: I think it is a duplicate...

Comment: I still like the idea of using swim caps. Just make sure it's a comfortable fit, then cut out a hole out at the top to make it more breathable, or make swiss-cheese holes throughout. And yes, it's a duplicate of that thread where we talked about it. Cycling skull caps may not stay on your head as well as swim caps will. Your ear protection idea is good, though, but it might get too hot for general practice. Good maybe for tournaments where you're knocking heads around? Of course the better idea is to simply tie your hair down somehow.